# Unable to attach a .txt file or .log file to mail and mailx command

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am trying to attach a .log file or .txt file to mail command to send an email once my ksh script executed.
I am unable to use mutt command as it has been not installed in my machine and i am not supposed to install it.
I have tried many ways by googling which has not been helped me to succeed.

Here is my requirement,I need to run some 10 sql queries and result need to send in the email via attachment. I have `Check.ksh` and i am running this by using `nohup` command.

```
nohup Check.ksh > Valid_Check.log 2>&1 &
```

In Check.ksh

```
typeset var TO="name@domain.com";
typeset var SUB="Report";
typeset var BODY="Check Completed";
typeset var ATTACHMENT=${FILE_PATH}/Valid_Check.log

if [ -f "${ATTACHMENT}" ]; then 
echo "Log file exist";
else
echo "No Log File";
fi

uuencode Valid_Check.log Valid_Check.log | mail -s "${SUB}" "${BODY}" ${TO}
```

and tried the below as well

```
#mailx -s "${SUB}" "${TO}" "${BODY}" < ${FILE_PATH}/Valid_Check.log

#cat ${FILE_PATH}/Valid_Check.log | mailx -s "${SUBJECT}" "${TO}" "${BODY}";
```

Above code throwing an error like "Valid... User unknown"

Any inputs would be helpful or any other simple/easy approach?

Thanks,

Comment: The error message suggests that `Valid` somehow ends up in `$TO` but the code you posted does not produce this result.

Comment: Using `uuencode` should definitely be your last resort. If your `mailx` supports attachments, definitely use this facility instead. MIME has been widely supported for over 20 years now.

Comment: Mixing a `$BODY` with uuencoded standard input might not be supported by your `mail` or `mailx` commands, but these are poorly standardized and have different capabilities on different platforms and of course also between versions. What platform are you on and what versions of there software packages are you using?

Comment: We are using Red Hat Linux version, and when i try this `mail -s "${SUB}" ${TO} <<< ${BODY}` then it is sending an email but with attachment not sure why it is not working.

Comment: There can only be one body in a traditional RFC822 email and it can come from the command line or standard input but not both. Again, I would suggest you try to find a supported way to send multipart MIME messages intead of legacy `uuencode` format. As a deperate fallback, append the uuencode data to the body with an empty line in between.

Comment: Actually MIME is also not installed, when i tried for `man MIME` it is saying no entry for MIME. Would it be possible for you to give the command as you suggested above (for this, As a deperate fallback, append the uuencode data to the body with an empty line in between.

Comment: MIME is a technology, not the name of a command. Any reasonably recent email software (like, from this century) supports it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

Comment: I think you'll find that I have already posted an answer along these lines.

Comment: I am not much familior with shell scripting but thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a recent enough `mailx`, use the `-a` option to add an attachment.

```
mailx -s "$SUB" -a "Valid_Check.log" "$TO" <<<"$BODY"
```

See also https://access.redhat.com/solutions/104833

If you are hopelessly stuck in a previous millennium and don't have any software which can handle proper attachments, the uuencode data should simply be appended to the body.

```
( echo "$BODY"; echo; uuencode Valid_check.log Valid_check.log ) |
mailx -s "$SUB" "$TO"
```

The basic approach suffers from a race condition, though - the existence of the output file indicates that the cron job has *started,* not finished. Putting the mail command at the end of the cron job would fix this; then, the email will only be sent when the previous step finishes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i don't have a recent enough mailx, so `mailx -a` is not working but the other `echo with uuencode` approach worked for me.Thanks agian!

Comment: Hi again,getting some NHÔ” characters while using the above uuencode in the attachment where as the log is having expected echo messages.Any help!? Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear where these characters are appearing.  `uuencode` simply translates the input into a text-only representation which should be reasonably robust against various mail transport issues.  If the extracted attachment contains things which were not present when you encoded it on the sending side, what exactly is failing?  If the input contained characters e.g. in an encoding you cannot identify, the email transport is doing what it's supposed to be doing, and the problem was present before you sent the file as well.

Comment: If `$BODY` begins with a dash, it's possible that you are producing an error message from `echo` which consumes part of the input.  Try `printf '%s' "$BODY"` to exclude this possibility.

Comment: These characters are appearing the txt file which has been attached and sent to the file,when i looked at the log file it is printing all the error messages which are there in `echo` but when i opened the file from mail then in some places these kind of characters are coming.And i have used `printf` option but still getting the same kind of messages.

Comment: It''s still not at all clear what you are asking.  Maybe post a new question with details of what the file looks like before and after sending it.  You might want to link to this question for background.

Comment: And when i executed the above mailx command for first time, i got same kind of characters for few error messages like when the message starts with NO or NO.OF so i have changed the messages in a different way and ran it worked fine but today when i tried the same it is printing the messages which starts with NO but in some places i am getting these kind of characters.

Comment: Post a new question with a short example.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363697/how-to-avoid-unknown-characters-while-sending-an-attachment-by-using-mailx-comma